# How to describe the set of "all computable functions" using Coq?

Tags: computability, coq, recursive

Would the set of all computable functions be just the set of all maps of the form

```
f : forall n : nat, P n -> nat
```

where `P : nat -> Prop`, and `(P n)` has a proof whenever `(f n)` is defined - so, `n` is in the domain of `f`. Is this some smaller set of maps actually computable by Coq, or is this what I want?

If not, is there an existing formalization? Using lambda calculus, or combinators K and S, or some basic concept of an algorithm?

Perhaps along with a proof of the Snm theorem - that says this set is enumerable?

Comment: Related: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4302/is-there-a-reasonable-automated-proof-system-for-tcs-theorems

Answer (score 2):

The usual definition of partial recursive functions using Turing machines and classical logic (with a few novelties) has been implemented in Coq: see

Zammit, Vincent (1997) [A Proof of the S-m-n theorem in Coq](http://kar.kent.ac.uk/21524/). Technical report. University of Kent, The University of Kent, Canterbury, Kent, UK